# Python package install failing

Tags: python

I'm trying to install the rpy2 package and can't get past a "The system cannot find the file specified". I'm not sure what file it can't find or why it isn't able to install (it is downloading the tar.gz file but won't install into the env).
I'm running on windows with python 3.6.8

```
Collecting rpy2
  Using cached rpy2-3.3.6.tar.gz (179 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\program files\alteryx\bin\miniconda3\envs\jupytertool_venv\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\paulj\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ih4008f_\\rpy2\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\paulj\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ih4008f_\\rpy2\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\paulj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-47z8bowi'
         cwd: C:\Users\paulj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ih4008f_\rpy2\
    Complete output (20 lines):
    cffi mode: CFFI_MODE.ANY
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\paulj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ih4008f_\rpy2\setup.py", line 115, in <module>
        c_extension_status = get_r_c_extension_status()
      File "C:\Users\paulj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ih4008f_\rpy2\setup.py", line 99, in get_r_c_extension_status
        *situation.get_r_flags(r_home, '--ldflags')
      File "C:\Users\paulj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ih4008f_\rpy2\rpy2\situation.py", line 210, in get_r_flags
        allow_empty=False)))
      File "C:\Users\paulj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ih4008f_\rpy2\rpy2\situation.py", line 179, in _get_r_cmd_config
        universal_newlines=True
      File "c:\program files\alteryx\bin\miniconda3\envs\jupytertool_venv\lib\subprocess.py", line 356, in check_output
        **kwargs).stdout
      File "c:\program files\alteryx\bin\miniconda3\envs\jupytertool_venv\lib\subprocess.py", line 423, in run
        with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
      File "c:\program files\alteryx\bin\miniconda3\envs\jupytertool_venv\lib\subprocess.py", line 729, in __init__
        restore_signals, start_new_session)
      File "c:\program files\alteryx\bin\miniconda3\envs\jupytertool_venv\lib\subprocess.py", line 1017, in _execute_child
        startupinfo)
    FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: [Issue in GitHub](https://github.com/rpy2/rpy2/issues/390) Hope this is helpful.

Comment: that sounds like the issue is it hasn't been compiled for windows hence its missing some key bits. I will try the one of the mirrors in that link thanks